# Print the list of an imported text file

Tags: python-3.x

What I am trying to do is:

- read the text from a file: **output.txt**
- enter it into the list and
- split it in a given range and
- then replace some string with another and
- print the list.

Here's the code I'm using:-

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for l in lines:
 storeSplit = ['  '.join(l.split()[1:6])]
 #print(storeSplit)
 for storeSplit_Iteraator in storeSplit:
    storeReplace = [storeSplit_Iteraator.replace('Fas ', 'FastEthernet')]
    for show in storeReplace:
        print ("thing is " + storeReplace[show])
```

It is giving me the error:-

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You're trying to access an element of the list `storeReplace` by using `[show]`, which is a string, and as the error tells you, list indices must be integers. Try just using `print("thing is " + show)` and see if you get what you expected.

Comment: @PyPingu it worked. :-) thnx bro